# Problems with mousewheel in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in the head-section:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#box').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
        var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down',
        vel = Math.abs(delta);
        alert(dir + ' at a velocity of ' + vel);
        return false;
    });
});
```

In firefox 5 nothing happens at all. In Chrome 13 and IE 9 I get "Down at a velocity of NaN", no matter at which direction I scroll.

How can I fix this? What I want to do is to check if the user is scorlliing upwards, or if he´s scrolling downwards.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `delta` is undefined which probably means you didn't include the proper plugin, or included it in the wrong place.

Don't know what you download, I've tried now with [this](http://brandonaaron.net/javascripts/plugins/mousewheel.js) and it's [working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/NWcPV/).

If you remove the external resource, it won't work as happens in your case.

Answer (score 9):

Not working either with new jQuery 2.0.1... well, it works but not as desired. This code only detect down movement (that means negative delta). I have tried this code and the result is always negative:

```
var num = 0;

$('#container').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e, delta) {
    if(delta > 0) {
        $("#output").text(++num);
    } else {
        $("#output").text(--num);
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `DOMMouseScroll` is the same as `mousewheel` but for Firefox.

**CORRECTION**

I have found this new code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined) and now it's working in Chrome and Firefox (I have fixed it) with jQuery 2.0.1. The problem was that the `delta` value returned was undefined.

```
function extractDelta(e) {
    if (e.wheelDelta) {
        return e.wheelDelta;
    }

    if (e.originalEvent.detail) {
        return e.originalEvent.detail * -40;
    }

    if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) {
        return e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    }
}

var num = 0;

$('#container').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e) {
    var d = extractDelta(e);

    if(d > 0) {
        $("#output").text(++num);
    } else {
        $("#output").text(--num);
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

`Container` and `output` are just two empty divs.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a cross-browser solution:

```
var onMouseWheel = function(e) {
    e = e.originalEvent;
    var delta = e.wheelDelta>0||e.detail<0?1:-1;
    alert(delta);
}
$("body").bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", onMouseWheel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine with jQuery 1.6.x, but does NOT work with jQuery 1.7.x 
Seems like something broke in jQuery.